# How to change default Administrator

Tags: cmd.exe, administrator, uac

When I open CMD as Administrator, the path is `C:\Users\Asus`. What I want is the default path when I open CMD is `C:\Users\Cloud___`. I have made this user as Administrator, but it doesn't work. Can someone tell me how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are like me, pressing start cmd and open that as administrator.

In this case, just opening administrator, you cannot change the default path. But there are a few workarounds.

## Opening a script as administrator

You can write a small script that changes the path and then launches an interactive command prompt. Instead of opening cmd from the start menu, you would open that script.

Here's an example of such script:

```
::  -- Open an interactive command prompt from a different path.

::  -- Lets hide commands for a cleaner experience.
    @echo off
    
::  -- Change the path to the user's profile (eg. c:\users\myuser). Change this to anything if desired.
    cd /d %USERPROFILE%
    
::  -- Start a new interactive command prompt to keep the script alive and become interactive.
    cmd /c cmd
    
::  -- Add commands below that you want to be executed if a user types exit from the cmd.
::  -- This section is completely optional and can be left out of your script.
    echo good bye
    pause
```

It will allow you to do exactly the same as administrator vs non-administrator. You could even do `net use g: \\myserver\share` to make a network mapping available in cmd as administrator if you wanted. Just put all those commands before making the script interactive.

## Use Windows Terminal

Microsoft created Windows Terminal, an app you can download from the microsoft store that creates a tabbed interface for multiple command prompts, powershell and other cli interfaces. Unlike cmd, if you open windows terminal as administrator, and you start a new command prompt instance, it will open in your profile path instead of c:\windows\system32 by default.

## Use WIN+R

When you use <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Windows Run command, you can type in a command. By default the last command entered is shown there, and you can use the dropdown box to select previous commands. Since this remembers commands, you can type the following command there and have it always ready:

```
cmd /k "cd /d %USERPROFILE%"
```

By default, if you press ok here, the command is executed normally. If you hold ctrl and shift while pressing Ok, or if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> the command will be run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

To open Command Prompt in a specific path, create a shortcut with `cmd /k cd "C:\Users\Cloud__"` and use it to start Cmd, Command Prompt will always open there.

Tip: If you want to run it always as Administrator, then in Shortcut Properties > Advanced > Check Run As Administrator > OK> OK.